# Deleted inactive picklist values thru automated way

Tags: picklist

I have huge list of inactive picklist values that needs to be deleted forever. Manually takes lot of time deleting in each instance, is there any automated way like Apex code or data loader to delete them in single shot? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I remember using an iMacro once, it's a browser automation tool. You need to do recording one delete, and then small changes in the script for looping and You are good.